# Google Maps API: how to reduce costs

Tags: api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am building a property listing for real estate and in backend (but also in frontend) I need to display Google Maps with a Pin.

The maps should not be interactive but simply display the position of the flat. No special pin icons, no other interactions.

I am on my staging environment and in 1 months the API's call generated a cost of more than 400 dollars that unfortunately I am going to pay...

How can I reduce the costs of Google Maps? It's really the first time I am implementing these API's...

Answer (score 4):

Hey so I ran into exactly the same problem whilst building a website for a real estate not too long ago.

We had 100's of property listings all with an interactive map that could filter nearby schools/shops etc. this was all relying on the Maps JavaScript API as well as the Places API which both become quite expensive when you're starting to get 10k requests a week!

Here was the learnings of a mad couple of weeks:

The Maps Embed API is free to use and by the sounds of it fits your needs perfectly, no need to programatically generate the map too, it just works as an iframe which you can set lattitude & longitude (or any other query for that matter) in the URL parameters of the iframe.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started

Check out this link below for constructing URL's and all available parameters:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map

Using this alone reduced our costs greatly so that we were covered by their free monthly usage. We then set the interactive map to only be served to users that request it by clicking a "Show Nearby" button. So the Embed API is acting like a bit of a facade.

Also learnt a lot about controlling your API's through Google Search Console, you want to be setting up usage alerts and also thresholds to ensure you never run any unexpected costs in the future. Also you want to be setting application restrictions (HTTP referrers).

With all this being said - get in touch with Google, they're very responsive to emails. If you explain the situation and all the measures put in place they can help if the pending bill is gonna make you broke!

They're really understanding and wiped my initial bill that was in the thousands and have been monitoring the project since.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to update the experience based upon user interaction with a low cost map. There are two lower cost maps that have fewer options than the full `new google.maps.Map()`:

1. Use an embedded map - no markers
2. Use a static map - markers, custom styles, no interactions

When the user clicks/hovers/etc on the map, replace it with a fully functional map. I made an [example of this at with a button](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/programmatic-load-button).

```js
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";

let map;

const center = { lat: 41.90476224706472, lng: 12.49822074385094 };
const zoom = 14;
const url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  version: "weekly",
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

  wrapper.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url}?center=${center.lat},${center.lng}&zoom=${zoom}&scale=2&size=${wrapper.clientWidth}x${wrapper.clientHeight}&key=YOUR_API_KEY)`;
  wrapper.addEventListener("click", () => {
    wrapper.remove();
    loader.load().then(() => {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center,
        zoom,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

### Notes

- won't reduce costs for cases where every user interacts with the more expensive map
- should improve page performance and lighthouse scores
- might add some complexity around css sizing of the elements
- join our discord server listed at https://developers.google.com/maps/developer-community#discord to discuss this further and match strategies to your particular use case.